# Input view for textfields in table view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I Have an UITableView with textfields in each row.

I want to access these textfields each in a different way like adding a picker view for one textfield, navigating to another view when clicked on one text field.

i know how to do it when these textfields are in a normalview but i never have done it before on tableview.

Please help.

Comment: I dont know where to write the code

Comment: in normal view if we take textfield and a pickerview i used connect them in IB but how to do it here as these textfields are there in tableview

Comment: have you try to set a tag to each textfield in cellForRowAtIndexPath? like textField.tag=indexPath.row and then access it by tag.

Comment: nope i didnt. Can u pls post a sample code?

Comment: I posted the code on the previous comment, just try it, then access to the textField with [self.view viewWithTag:yourTag];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is where to put the code to handle user interaction with your table view cells. Well the proper place to do that is the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of your table view controller.

However, there are a few *caveats*.

- You need to add the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol to your table view controller.
- You can distinguish between the active `UITextFields` with tags, as suggested in other answers.
- However, recycling the cells can lead to big confusion about the text fields. So make sure you update that id tag in the part of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that is not creating new cells.
- You should **not** use a `UITextField` when you want another controller to pop up. In this case, just use a `UILabel` or the provided `textLabel` property of `UITableViewCell`. Push another controller when the user selects the row.
- Only use a `UITextField` if you want the keyboard to pop up without leaving the table view.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to give tag to each textfield like

```
textfield.tag = indexpath.row;
```

according to tag you can move ahead...

Answer (score 0):

And one more thing while assigning tag to text field, don't forgot to this line

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
   reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: Can i tell you why?...i think there is no relationship with this line of code and the assingment of the tag to the textfield.